# How to find game load time in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, scripting

I'd like to find the time between when I press the play button and when the game actually starts. Is there a builtin function or a system function I could use to measure this?

I tried using Unity's builtin time functions to store a start time in Awake() and an end time in the first frame of the game. Then printed endTime - startTime - Time.deltaTime (Time it took to run the first frame). My results were coming out at about 0.3 seconds when taking the same time with my phone's stopwatch was giving me about 3 seconds.

Comment: Why not make 2 static variables, when you click start set the first one to Time.time, load the scene using the `LoadSceneAsync` have a coroutine that checks the status of it and when it is fully loaded the load time is `Time.time - playPressedTime`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is: `Awake` might not be called instantly after pressing the <kbd>Play</kbd> button. Unity prepares and loads the assets in the background and than enters playmode.

But, Yes! There actually is a builtin possibility in the Editor (Only in the editor not in a build or something). Here a short script I made (attach it to any `GameObject` in your scene):

```
using System;
#if UNITY_EDITOR // Note that without this pre-processors any build will fail
using UnityEditor;
#endif
using UnityEngine;

// ExecuteInEditMode makes this component also execute if not in PlayMode
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class LoadTimeTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    // public only for debugging
    public long playButtonTime;
    public long startTime;

#if UNITY_EDITOR

    private void OnPlayModeChanged(PlayModeStateChange stateChange)
    {
        switch (stateChange)
        {
            case PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode:
                // save the system time when leaving the edit mode
                playButtonTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                break;

            case PlayModeStateChange.EnteredPlayMode:
                // save and compare the system time when entering play mode
                startTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                var difference = (startTime - playButtonTime) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

                Debug.Log("Load Time was: " + difference + "ms", this);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Register to the playModestaeChanged event
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += OnPlayModeChanged;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // Unregister from the playModeStateChanged event
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged -= OnPlayModeChanged;
    }

#endif
}
```

- [`ExecuteInPlayMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) is required so the component registers to the `EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged` event already when in the edit mode
- [`System.DateTime.Now.Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_Ticks) are the current System times nanoseconds.
- [`EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-playModeStateChanged.html) ... well .. this event is triggered whenever the playmode changes
- `(startTime - playButtonTime) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;`: Since I used ticks which are the **nano**seconds of the system time we have to devide by TimeSpan.TicksPerMilliseconds (= 10.000) to get a bit more readable value in milliseconds instead.

---

**Note:** I just made a check: Apparently this will be called **after** all `Awake`, `OnEnable` and `Start` calls and **after** the **first** frame is finished.